# How to control decimal point in Common Lisp format?

Tags: common-lisp

How to pass a value to a function that control how many number in decimal point to print.

I can do with `$` or `f`, e.g

```
(format t "~,3f" 3.141592)
(format t "~2$" 3.141592)
```

But how to do something like this

```
(defun control-format (x)
  (format nil "~,xf" 3.141592))
```

So we can pass any number as argument to `control-format` to control how many decimal number we want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `v` instead of a literal number:

```
* (dotimes (i 8)
    (format t "~,vf~%" i pi))
3.
3.1
3.14
3.142
3.1416
3.14159
3.141593
3.1415927
NIL
*
```